# Why isn't that C++ const templated vector initialised before being used?

Tags: c++

**Update:** the question is why the code below (MWE) works as it is and not as I would expect it to.

For personal convenience, I created the following templated vector const:

```
// shorthand for loops, etc.
template <size_t N>
const vector<size_t> range = []() {
    vector<size_t> res(N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) res[i] = i;
    cout << "Created range<" << N << ">: [";
    for (auto x: res) cout << x << ' ';
    cout << ']' << endl;
    return res;
}();
```

So that further, I can write more laconic loops like the following:

```
for (auto i : range<42>) do_something(i);
```

However, I realised (after some debugging) that it seems to be not guaranteed that all required instantiations of `range<N>` are initialised before usage! This is rather counter-intuitive so I think if I am doing something wrong.

More precisely, I have the following MWE:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template <size_t N>
const vector<size_t> range = []() {
    cout << "Initialising range<" << N << ">" << endl;
    vector<size_t> result(N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) result[i] = i;
    return result;
}();

template <size_t K>
class Data {
   private:
    size_t m_code;

   public:
    size_t get_code() const { return m_code; }

    constexpr static size_t cardinality = K + 1;

    explicit Data(size_t code);

    const static vector<Data> elems;
};

template <size_t K>
const vector<Data<K>> Data<K>::elems = []() {
    cout << "Creating Data elements for K=" << K << endl;
    vector<Data<K>> xs;
    for (size_t i : range<Data<K>::cardinality>) xs.push_back(Data<K>(i));
    return xs;
}();

template <size_t K>
Data<K>::Data(size_t code) {
    m_code = code;

    cout << "At the moment, range<" << K << "> is [";
    for (auto k : range<K>)
        cout << k << ' ';  // <<< Shouldn't range<K> be already initialised here?..
    cout << "] (len=" << range<K>.size() << ")" << endl;
}

int main() {
    cout << ">>> Inside main()" << endl;
    constexpr size_t K = 2;

    cout << "Data elements:" << endl;
    for (const auto &X : Data<K>::elems) {
        cout << "Element Data(" << X.get_code() << ")" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Now, range<" << K << "> is [";
    for (auto k : range<K>) cout << k << ' ';
    cout << "] (len=" << range<K>.size() << ")" << endl;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Initialising range<3>
Creating Data elements for K=2
At the moment, range<2> is [] (len=0)
At the moment, range<2> is [] (len=0)
At the moment, range<2> is [] (len=0)
Initialising range<2>
>>> Inside main()
Data elements:
Element Data(0)
Element Data(1)
Element Data(2)
Now, range<2> is [0 1 ] (len=2)
```

I don't really understand why it is working as it is. I mean, I would expect a `const` vector (or any vector!) to be initialised before it is used and thus `range<2>` to be of length two any time I use it in the code.

Comment: I expected `range<2>` to have a length two at the moment I use it in the code. My question is why it is not the case. Laconic for loops is just and example when I encountered this behaviour which I don't understand. I will update the question a bit perhaps, so it's more clear.

Comment: You can fix it by writing `range<K>;` just before the `for` loop in `elems` lambda, although I cannot entirely explain why

Comment: Well, my question is actually about _explanation_ or understanding :)

Comment: `... range = []() {...` the empty parens are optional, so could be simplified a couple characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dynamic initialization of non-local static storage duration variables resulting from (non-explicit) template specializations is *unordered*, i.e. sequenced indeterminately, meaning that the order in which the initializations happen is unspecified. It does not take into account either dependencies between the variables, or order of definition, or order of instantiation.

Therefore your program has undefined behavior, since `Data<2>::elems`, instantiated from the use in `main`, has *unordered dynamic initialization* and uses `range<2>` and `range<3>`, both of which also have *unordered dynamic initialization*. Because it is unspecified whether the former or the latter are initialized first, it is possible that you access `range<2>` or `range<3>` before their initializations have begun, causing undefined behavior.

This can be resolved by using `std::array` instead of `std::vector` for `range` and in its initializer (and removing the `cout` statements in the initializer), so that the initializer becomes a constant expression. Then `range<K>` will not have *dynamic initialization*, but *constant initialization*, which is always performed before any dynamic initialization, i.e. before `Data<K>::elems` will use it.

In addition you should then declare `range` as `constexpr` to make sure that the initializer is indeed a constant expression. Otherwise you might still get dynamic initialization and the undefined behavior without warning, for example when you make a change that accidentally causes the initializer not to be a constant expression anymore.

Comment: Actually, even without `constexpr`, using `array` helped - but of course, I will make it `constexpr` to make sure it always works.

And `cout` is used here just to log order of calls.

Comment: Hmm... although now with `constexpr` it complaints that array is uninitialised

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka You need to initialize every variable used in a `constexpr` function, so write `array<...> arr{};` instead of `array<...> arr;`. Otherwise your lambda will not be `constexpr` and calling it will not be a constant expression, falling exactly in the trap I mentioned regarding not using `constexpr`.

Comment: Is there also UB due to the same issue with `range<3>`? I.e. would it be legal for the compiler to  execute the `Data<2>::elems` lambda before initializing `range<3>` ?

Comment: Also is there any possible code we could write inside the `elems` lambda , or at file scope immediately next to it, to force `range<K>` and `range<K+1>` to be initialized before the lambda is run?  (supposing we do not make the change to constant initialization, that is)

Comment: @M.M I don't think there is. I think you would need to put either of `elems` or `range` in a function as local static variables in order to make this work.

Comment: @walnut But can I have similar type of problem with _constant initialisation_? I mean, if similar type of initialisations are done for `constexpr`-objects (e.g. arrays) - is that guaranteed that dependencies are satisfied?..

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka Constant initialization happens if the initializer is a constant expression, meaning that the compiler must have evaluated every value used at compile-time, so there is no initialization order issue. If the compiler encounters a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion referring to a `constexpr` variable, it either has to figure out its value (by running the initializer first) or the expression using it cannot be a constant expression, i.e. constant initialization.